# How to point on the concrete Dockerfile for the docker build command inside the jenkins pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerfile, jenkins-docker

Please let me know how to point on the concrete Dockerfile for the docker build command inside the jenkins pipeline?

I am trying to give a docker build from a Jenkins pipeline, I am using a common code to run this build and would want the pipeline to access a folder where the dockerfile is. How do I let the docker know how to find this dockerfile which is in a different folder location.

Comment: What does your pipeline code look like now?  [Using Docker with Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers) in the Jenkins documentation has some specific examples of alternate build contexts and Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 3):

With `sh` in a declarative pipeline:

```
sh '''
    docker build -t '<myimagename>' \
        --file <somewhereelse>/Dockerfile .
'''
```

[Within a scripted pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers):

```
docker.build("my-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "-f ${dockerfile} ./dockerfiles")
```

Comment: I used something like this below                                                                                                       def dockerfile = 'Dockerfile'
  if(env.tag && !exist){
      app = docker.build("dockerregistry.abc.net/messagebroker:"+env.tag, "-f ${Dockerfile} ./trunk")                                                                                                        It is throws error as '+ docker build -t dockerregistry.abc.net/messagebroker:0.8.9 -f Dockerfile ./trunk
unable to prepare context: path "./trunk" not found'. It is not able go to the path. Please help

Comment: Use the `tree` or `ls -l` command to debug your workspace, or go to your workspace path on the machine (usually `/var/jenkins_home/workspace`).

Comment: Even after adding the complete right path (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/messagebroker) for it to find the dockerfile it is still unable to find and throws the error : " unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/docker_build/Dockerfile: no such file or directory " . Is there something else to be changed or added to the docker.build command ?

Comment: I guess you have a symlink there. Can you re-try with the symlinked path?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what exactly do you mean by retry with the symlinked path ? I quite did not understand what and how I should try.

Comment: It seems, that your Dockerfile is [symlinked](https://wiki.debian.org/SymLink). Can you try with the original path of the Dockerfile again? From the error it's seems that either Docker can't follow the symlink or the symlink is broken.

Comment: I used the hard link and still it is not able to access the path. I get this error : + docker build -t dockerregistry.abc.net/messagebroker:0.8.9 -f Dockerfile ./messagebroker
unable to prepare context: path "./messagebroker" not found

Comment: You should edit your original or open a new question.

Comment: Even if I give he full path its throwing error : unable to prepare context: path "./var/lib/jenkins/workspace/messagebroker" not found. Inside Jenkins workspace I can see the Dockerfile.

Comment: @CharuRao maybe check your permissions (also for the user running Jenkins).